# Which Python library supports HTTP pipelining?

Tags: python, http, https

[HTTP pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) is a technique in which multiple HTTP requests are sent on a single TCP (transmission control protocol) connection without waiting for the corresponding responses.

Python http clients like `requests` and `urllib3` does not support it.
`dugong` is not yet stable and does not work on `Windows 10` and `Python 3.8.5`.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do it on python 2.7 / httplib.
Before request:

```
conn._HTTPConnection__state = httplib._CS_IDLE
```

Before getresponse:

```
conn._HTTPConnection__state = httplib._CS_REQ_SENT
```

Where conn is the connection returned by httplib.HTTPSConnection.
In my case all requests were of the same type, same headers, except for one variable in GET string. Dunno if this will work with different request types.